# Deep clone object in Javascript except Object.assign

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, clone

`Object.assign` doesn't deep copy an object. considering following code it should print `0 0 0 1` but it is printing `0 0 1 1`.

```js
var obj = {
  "value": {
    "default": 0
  }
};
var newo = Object.assign({}, obj);

console.log(obj.value.default);
console.log(newo.value.default);

newo.value.default = 1;

console.log(obj.value.default);
console.log(newo.value.default);
```

I know we can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`. but is that a best practice solution?

Comment: If your object doesn't hold any circular references, I think it `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` is the way to go

Comment: Object.assign will keep references, the JSON.parse/JSON.stringify trick can really deepClone.

Comment: Be careful, though: the JSON stringify/parse method will fail if your object contains circular references *or* any values that are not primitive types (so functions, instances of other classes, etc.)